# Add a loader while an if else statement is being evaluated

Tags: reactjs

Im having trouble inserting a timed loader while I evaluate an if else statement.

My goal is to render a loader for a few seconds while the statement `payload.length > 0 ? (/*Do stuff*/) : (/*Do something else*/)` is evaluating. Any feedback is appreciated.

> This is the loader I want to add for a few seconds

```
        <LoaderContainer>
            <RingLoader size={100} />
        </LoaderContainer>
```

> This is my code

```
return payload.length > 0 ? (
            <Container>
                <FilterBarContainer>
                    <FilterBar onChangeValue={onChangeValue}/>
                </FilterBarContainer>
                <FilterContainer>
                    {tabData.map(/* Displays tabs */)}
                </FilterContainer>
                {finalData.length === 0 ? (
                    <EmptyTabContainer>
                        <p>/* Empty Tab */</p>
                    </EmptyTabContainer>
                ) : (
                    finalData.map(
                        payload => (/* Displays payload info */),
                    )
                )}
            </Container>
        ) :(
            <EmptyPageContainer>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon="ticket-alt" className="icon" />
                <p>/* This user has no tickets */</p>
            </EmptyPageContainer>
        );
```

Comment: Is Do Stuff async?

Comment: Is your component that big? The better context of your code, the better we can help you.

Comment: @mousetail Do stuff contains the lines of code inside of the <Container> tag

Comment: So the container takes a long time to render? If a component takes a noticable amount of time to render you have bigger problems. Anything that takes significant time should be in a separate, preferably async method.

Comment: it takes a second or less but its enough for me to see the else case. so initially when the payload is fetch for a brief second the if else evaluates to "else" but then switches to the "if". I want to avoid displaying "This user has no tickets" even if its for a brief 1 sec or less and instead show a loader @mousetail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your render method add the following code:

```
render(){
   if(this.state.loading){
      return (
        <LoaderContainer>
            <RingLoader size={100} />
        </LoaderContainer>
      );
   }

   return(
      // The rest of your code.
   );
```

Then when you define your state you need to specify `state.loading: true`:

```
state = {
   loading: true
}
```

And whenever you are ready to remove the loader, just use:

```
this.setState({
   loading: false
});
```

### Why?

Remember that every state change in React causes the `render` method to execute again. This will cause that when you update the state of `loading` to `false`, the loading component will no longer be rendered unless you set the `loading` state back to `true`.

***Note:*** The only thing left to you is to implement what do you want to render when the state of `loading` is set to `false`.

#### EDIT:

To render the loader only for a certain (but specific) time, you could use `setTimeout` at the `componentDidMount` method:

```
componentDidMount(){
   setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({loading:false});
   },2000); // 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
}
```

I really do not recommend this, but if you aren't using an async function to fetch data or anything, then using `setTimeout` seems fine to simulate the page load.

Comment: Is there a way to add a timer on the loader " <LoaderContainer><RingLoader size={100} /></LoaderContainer>" so it can only render for 1 or 2 seconds?

Comment: @CatGirl19 Sure. I edited my answer. Hope it solves your comment.